# Where was an element placed after sorting?

Tags: jquery

Hod do you determine the new index of an element sorted using jQuery UI sortable?

i have an un-ordered list and every list item has an id...when i drag it up or down and place it, i need to know the new position (vaguely speaking, like the id of element that moved to make room for this new element)  ...is that even possible?
i tried using the .mousedown and .mouseup events and getting this.id...but it returns the same element being dragged both the times.

In short we knw the element being dragged but hw can we know where it was finally laid to rest?

the code is simple...it is actually a table

```
---------HTML----------------
<table id="activities">
<thead>
<tr><th>Activity Name</th><th>Activity Number</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr id="node-1">
<td>Welcome</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr id="node-2">
<td>Eat</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="node-3">
<td>Walk</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr id="node-4">
<td>Sleep</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now im making the rows sortable by jquery:

```
$("#activities tbody").sortable();
```

Now when the user drags a row up or down, i need to change the activity number accordingly...for example if he drags the "welcome" row down under the "eat" row, that will mean the the activity number of "welcome" row is now 2 (which was previously 1) and the activity number of "eat" row is 1....to display the new updated table with correct activity number, i need to know the where it was dropped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `beforeStop` function within the `sortable()` method:

```
$("#activities tbody").sortable(
    {
        beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
            newIndex = $(ui.helper).index('table tbody tr');
            alert(newIndex);
        }
    }
);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8uxgQ/);

---

**Edited** to provide information on retrieving the `id` of the dropped element:

```
$("#activities tbody").sortable(
    {
        beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
            var index = $(ui.helper).index( 'table tbody tr' );
            alert( 'index = ' + index + '; id = ' + $(ui.helper).attr( 'id' ) );
        }
    }
);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8uxgQ/2/).

---

**Edited** in response to question, in comments, from the OP:

> ...problem solved!! If it's not a matter of trouble for you, can you explain the code..?

Of course:

- `newIndex = $(ui.helper).index('table tbody tr');`
  This selects the current 'helper element', and uses the jQuery `index()` method to find where that element fits within the elements returned by the selector passed to the method, in this case the elements returned by `table tbody tr`. If there is more than one `table` and `tbody` on the page this index will be wrong, so selecting by the table's `id` would be (`index('#idOfTable tbody tr')`) would be preferable.
- `theID = ui.helper.id;`
  This returns the `id` of the item held in the `ui.helper` variable (the just-dropped element).
- The `alert()` is just a routine JavaScript alert.

References:

- [`sortable()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)
- `beforeStop` (from the above link, select the 'events' menu, and then click on `beforeStop`):

> > This event is triggered when sorting stops, but when the placeholder/helper is still available.
> >
> > Code examples
> >
> > Supply a callback function to handle the beforeStop event as an init option.

```
        $( ".selector" ).sortable({
            beforeStop: function(event, ui) { ... }
        });
```

- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: Thanks a bunch david!! u r a genius!! ....prblm solved!! if its nt a matter of trouble for u, can u explain the code a lil bit?

Comment: Thank you, kindly. I've tried to explain my code somewhat, but if you could clarify which parts you don't understand I'll try and explain further.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [`toArray` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#methods) and the [`stop` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#events).

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/kMm2a/)

Comment: thanks pomeh...but i tried the stop event and its giving me the table body instead of the row-id...any way i can get the row id?

Answer (score 1):

Not to say that the answers were worng but i found another simple way of knowing the index position where the element was dropped. In the stop method do this:

```
alert(ui.item[0].rowIndex)
```

and it will tell u the new index position. Additionally if u want to know the starting index (the position before dragging) then we hav to give the start event. the syntax is same as above. heres the full example func

```
var sourceIndex="";
$("#activities tbody").sortable(
    {
        start: function(event, ui) {
            sourceIndex=ui.item[0].rowIndex;
            id=ui.item[0].rowIndex;
        }
    }
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            alert("source index="+sourceIndex);
            alert("destination index"+ui.item[0].rowIndex);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: The `rowIndex` property is only available on.. `<tr>` elements. So this will work in your case only.